# Declare a non-zero global static variable

Tags: vba, excel

I want to declare a static variable `pos`, the following code works:

```
Dim pos As Integer

Sub increment()
    MsgBox pos
    pos = pos + 1
end Sub

Sub decrement()
    MsgBox pos
    pos = pos - 1
end Sub
```

The problem here is that `pos` always starts from `0`. What if I want it to start always from `10` let's say? I tried `Dim pos As Integer = 10` or `Public pos As Integer = 10`, they did not compile.

Comment: @Aiken, as the OP has stated, ***Declare a non-zero global static variable*** which is different from Constant. So I do not think this is a Duplicate of that thread.

Comment: @PaulFrancis The fact that constants come up as an answer to the other question doesn't change the fact that the *Questions* are almost identical. The OP of this question even states that they tried `Public pos as Integer = 10` and this failed to compile, the linked question asks why `Public MyVariable As Integer = 123` does not compile, seems like a dupe to me.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the value of an integer datatype outside of a sub or function. Think of it as a Module. That area, where you tried to declare your variable, is only reserved for declaration statements.

By default, a declared integer value is 0, so that explains why you're getting 0 for `pos`.

I would suggest that you make a particular sub where you'd initialize the values your global variable values and call it whenever you need it.

```
Sub InitGlobalVarVal()
Pos = 0
'And so on
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As VBA does not like it when you initialize values in the declaration. You need to create a Function, something like

```
Dim pos As Integer

Function initVal()
    pos = 10
End Function
```

This function needs to be called as soon as the file is opened and should be done only once, so call this function using the WorkBook_Open event. As it is called when the workbook is opened and will be executed once, thus achieving the need.

Comment: OP has tagged the question as `excel-vba` so there's no DB file involved here.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have a static variable there. You have to actually declare the variable as `Static` in order for it to *truly* be static.

   ```
   Static pos As Integer
   ```
2. How you initialize the variable may depend on your use case. If this code resides in a standard module (`.bas`) then just check for a value of zero prior to using it.

   ```
   If pos = 0 Then
       pos = baseValue
   End If
   ```

   But that *might* be buggy if zero is a valid value. It would be much better to have this code reside in a class (`.cls`) module where it's value can be initialized when the class is created.

   ```
   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       pos = baseValue
   End Sub
   ```
3. You can save the value IN a cell of the worksheet like $z$1000

Comment: Global variables are inherently `Static`, no?

Comment: @TimWilliams [not exactly](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141693), but the difference may be negligible at a global level. On further inspection on OP's code. I don't believe they meant `Static` though. I can't think of a use for a static variable at a module scope...

Comment: Actually, I *can*, but it involves classes.

Comment: @TimWilliams let's say I have a class where I want to count the number of *instances* of that class. I would use a static variable there at the class (module) level. All instances of the class would share that variable and have the same count. A global variable would reset after the last class was destroyed, while a static one would remain so long as the program is still running. I'm not sure I'm being clear and this is kind of chatty, so feel free to drop by the [VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) if you'd like to talk about it.

Comment: I guess I should have inluded  "in a regular module" in my comment.  I understand the implications of Static Class variables (which I'm not sure is even supported in VBA - did you try it out?).

Comment: I guess you do @TimWilliams. My apologies. I didn't realize I was talking to a gold vba badge holder...

Comment: You can't use a module-level Static in VBA - has to be in a procedure.  I forget that myself.